# CookieTempDataProvider causes CryptographicException

Tags: c#, session, cookies, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core app (1.1 targeting full framework) that uses TempDataProvider to store some metadata about the currently logged-in user, such as their "display name" and some other preferences for the app. In my Startup.cs `ConfigureServices` method I have added the line

```
services.AddSingleton<ITempDataProvider, CookieTempDataProvider>();
```

which is populated after login using (for example)

```
TempData["DisplayName"] = login.DisplayName;
```

This works well, creating an encrypted, chunked session cookie for the user named `.AspNetCore.Mvc.CookieTempDataProvider`. I can "peek" and clear on logout, etc. as I expect. However after some interval - perhaps the app pool going idle, but the browser session remaining active - I receive a CryptographicException:

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The key {guid} was not found in the key ring

It *appears* that the browser session cookie is still good, but the server has lost its ability to decrypt and use it. Currently the only way to resolve is to manually clear the cookie and let the app create a new one.

Is there any way to protect against this behavior? I do want the contents of the cookie to be difficult/impossible to forge, and this seemed like a valid mechanism to achieve that.

Comment: You could have stored display name as a claim. How did you authenticate the user?

Comment: @Win That's true, displayname is a poor example because it's the only item being stored here that's at all related to identity. I'm using ASP.NET Identity for authentication, but don't want to mix identity claims with session-level user app preferences. As I understand the identity payload should be kept as small as possible, which is why I was trying to use this as a supplemental store for non-identity session data.

Comment: We have the same problem. We get a `CryptographicException` with the message `The temp data cookie .AspNetCore.Mvc.CookieTempDataProvider could not be loaded.`. This seems to happen whenever the app pool restarts and clients make requests with the previously generated `.AspNetCore.Mvc.CookieTempDataProvider` cookie. While the warning messages are annoying, they don't look like they impact the users at all, as a new cookie is generated and sent to the client when this problem happens.

Comment: @JohnnyOshika i am being logged out of my serverless application probably due to this error/warning. is there any solution to this?

Comment: @ChUsman When you say you're being logged out, are cookies being wiped out? You'll have to inspect the response headers to see why things are happening. It's been a long time since I looked at this.